# i am using axios to get data to display in the page but what is displayed is object promise not value

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

i am using nuxt and inside there is a loop in which i call a function to get me the name of the teacher to display. but instead what is displayed is object promise not the name of the teacher

```
methods: {
    async teacherName (id) {
      try {
        const response = await this.$axios.get(`/users/${id}`)
        const data = response.data
        const result = `${data.firstName} ${data.lastName}`
        return result
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the template code? and please tell me the expected data shape.

Comment: thank you, this issue wouldn't resolve so i made both requests in the async created and the data fetched from one end point in an api i used it with the second end point of the same api to fetch the data that method was supposed to fetch and it worked out, anyways thank you really